# Postfix and Dovecot Virtual Mailboxes

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, mail-server

I have been setting up a home mail server on my Raspberry Pi using Dovecot and Postfix. This is all very new to me, and I've struggled my way through.

Now I'm on to trying to setup virtual mailboxes, and I've hit a brick wall.

The Virtual Mailbox 'seb@larp.events' SEEMS to be receiving e-mail in Postfix. I can send a message to it, and then see the e-mail appended to the maildir using cat (`sudo cat /mnt/pidrive1/virtualMailboxes/larp.events/seb`) But when I telnet into the mailbox, Dovecot gives me the following:

> pi@raspberrypi:/mnt/pidrive1/virtualMailboxes/dovecot $ telnet
> localhost 143 Trying ::1... Trying 127.0.0.1... Connected to
> localhost. Escape character is '^]'.
>
> - OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE LITERAL+ STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN] Dovecot (Raspbian) ready. a login
>   "seb@larp.events" "password" a OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR
>   LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES
>   THREAD=REFS THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT MULTIAPPEND URL-PARTIAL CATENATE
>   UNSELECT CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1
>   CONDSTORE QRESYNC ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH
>   LIST-STATUS BINARY MOVE SNIPPET=FUZZY LITERAL+ NOTIFY SPECIAL-USE]
>   Logged in b select inbox
> - FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft)
> - OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft *)] Flags permitted.
> - 0 EXISTS
> - 0 RECENT
> - OK [UIDVALIDITY 1634050202] UIDs valid
> - OK [UIDNEXT 1] Predicted next UID b OK [READ-WRITE] Select completed (0.366 + 0.000 + 0.365 secs). c logout
> - BYE Logging out c OK Logout completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs). Connection closed by foreign host.

My suspicion is that somehow I've set Dovecot up to manage its own set of virtual mailboxes, so its showing me its own virtual mailboxes rather than the ones that Postfix is delivering mail to... But I haven't a clue how to fix this... Can anybody help? Or spot the obvious mistake I'm bound to have made and tell me how to fix it? Thanks!

Dovecot-10-mail.conf: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am4Mh1i9vpw7hdtNxRxawyHmN4W3Pw?e=fGz7nF

Dovecot.conf: https://1drv.ms/t/s!Am4Mh1i9vpw7hdtRyKhC5OQ3FmzGpQ?e=JNVfqB

Postfix main.cf: https://1drv.ms/t/s!Am4Mh1i9vpw7hdtPFmlGbcbRrQmWWA?e=n1QxW7

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed it! For reference, I added the following to dovecot.conf:

```
service auth {
        unix_listener auth-client {
                group = postfix
                mode = 0660
                user = postfix
        }
        user = root
}
```

And everything sprang into life!